# Is it valid to overload function with extra non-deducible template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The following code compiles and works fine with gcc (9), clang (11) and msvc (16.28):

```cpp
template <class A>
struct X {
    A a;

    constexpr X(A a) : a{a} { }
};

template <class A>
constexpr auto fn(X<A> const& x) {
    return X<A>(x.a - 1);
}


template <class Xs, class A>
constexpr auto fn(X<A> const& x) {
    return Xs(x.a - 1);
}

constexpr X<int> x1{3};
constexpr auto x2 = fn(x1);
constexpr auto x3 = fn<X<double>>(x1);
```

There are two `fn` functions with identical declarations except for the extra `Xs` parameter in the second one.

I'd like to be sure that this is standard-accepted and not something that these compilers provide as extra? Since all 3 do, I'd guess this would be standard, but you never know.

I'd also like to know if my assumptions as to why this work/would be standard are correct:

- in the call `fn(x1)`, `Xs` cannot be deduced so the second overload of `fn` is discarded gently (SFINAE?)?
- in the call `fn<Xs>(x1)`, the first overload would then be `fn(X<X<int>>)` which does not match the argument `x1`, thus the first overload is also discarded?

Comment: Mostly, it is not SFINAE which rejects second overload, as there are not even a substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are two `fn` functions with identical declarations except for the extra `Xs` parameter in the second one.

That's fine, you can overload function templates using different arguments or different template arguments.

> - in the call `fn(x1)`, `Xs` cannot be deduced so the second overload of `fn` is discarded gently (SFINAE?)?

Yes, except it's not SFINAE, but overload resolution. The S in SFINAE stands for substitution. When a template argument can't be deduced, no substitution takes place.

It's described in [[temp.over]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.over#1):

> ... For each function template, ***if the argument deduction and checking succeeds***, the template-arguments (deduced and/or explicit) are used to synthesize the declaration of a single function template specialization which is ***added*** to the candidate functions set to be used in ***overload resolution***.

With regard to the second bullet (`fn<X<double>>(x1)`), both templates can synthesize a valid declaration, but `X<int>` isn't convertible to `X<X<double>>`, so the second overload is selected as the only viable one.

Note: when multiple template overloads are viable, [partial ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) is performed to determine the most specialized template.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure it was not SFINAE due to the "non-substitution". If I understand the quote it means that in `fn(x1)`, you can synthesize `fn<int>(X<int>)` from the first overload but you cannot synthesize anything from the second one because you cannot deduce `Xs`, while in `fn<X<int>>(x1)`, you synthesize both `fn<X<int>>(X<int>)` and `fn<X<int>, int>(X<int>)` and only the second overload matches, right?

Comment: When multiple overloads are viable, template specializations or not, they are first compared based on conversion sequences. Only if that comparison yields a result of, roughly speaking, "equally good", do we get to the tie breakers, one of them being partial ordering.

Comment: Interestingly, this would be visible in this case if the second call were `fn<X<int>>(x1)`. In this case, both overloads are viable, as there is a conversion from `X<int>` to `X<X<int>>` for the first overload, but the second one has a better conversion (identity), so the second one is chosen. And this happens even though neither template is more specialized than the other according to the partial ordering rules. cc @Holt